# Sharing gradients between the related classes in pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pytorch, torchvision

I am implementing a classifier with multi-label predictions. For the moment, there are only 5 classes. Following is the snippet of the code. So far I have no problem.

But I would like to further extend it where gradients between the related tasks (constrained by a matrix **W** which encodes the relatedness between the tasks) is shared. For example: there are five different classes **a, b,c, d, e** . I computed gradient for the mis-classification of **a** and updated the parameters. From the matrix **W** I discovered that task **e** is also related. I would also like to update the parameters for the task **e** with the gradients computed while predicting **a** with the rate encoded by **W**. Here **W** is precomputed and fixed.

I have no idea how to do it in PyTorch. I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

```py
class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, image_size=128, conv_dim=64, c_dim=5, repeat_num=6):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()
        layers = []
        layers.append(nn.Conv2d(3, conv_dim, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1))
        layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.01))

        curr_dim = conv_dim
        for i in range(1, repeat_num):
            layers.append(nn.Conv2d(curr_dim, curr_dim*2, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1))
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.01))
            curr_dim = curr_dim * 2 

        kernel_size = int(image_size / np.power(2, repeat_num))
        self.main = nn.Sequential(*layers)
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(curr_dim, 5, kernel_size=kernel_size, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x): 
        h = self.main(x)
        out_cls = self.conv2(h)
        return out_cls.view(out_cls.size(0), out_cls.size(1))
```

Comment: Not a real answer but I'm assuming you could call `optimizer.step()` twice, as that applies the current gradient. You would have to multiply the gradient with the factor from your correlation matrix in between.

Answer (score 0):

First you can propose different objective functions that only related to your tasks. Then you can do optimizations based on different optimizers related to different objective functions.